# Creating Java Classes for business logic without depending on a FacesContext

Tags: xpages

Ok, apologises for the title but I don't know how to word this.
Basically I've come across sessionCloning via the XPagesToolkit and XPageAgents, which I assume is implementing using a technique described here http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99U64Q

I initially used it to run existing java code which was triggered by an xpage but could take a while to run. Trouble is most of the existing code I have in one way or another relies on a FacesContext, either in order to get access to common beans for settings or just for basic logging.  This then causes an error when triggered via an XPagesAgent as I assume there's no facescontext.  I don't really want to end up duplicating code and creating different versions of the business logic.

So I guess I have 2 questions..

1) To refer to beans from java code I can use a Factory method as described here instead of directly going via the variableResolver... 
http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-98U9EK, however I don't get how to create a bean object manually and still pick up the custom properties which may have been set in the faces config. Is there a way to read those somehow? e.g. if you were to create a dBar object manually how would you pickup the logdb path from the faces-config?

2) How do people 'do' logging in a way which will always work regardless of context? I gather most people now use the debugToolbar or the XPagesOpenLogger but both of those appear to be dependant on a facescontext.  I don't want to stop using them but will have to in order to make my java code compatible outside of an xpage. At the moment most methods have some kind of try/catch with a call to dBar.error(e). Perhaps the answer is to create an interface which connects the dBarToolbar and the original prexpages openlogger java class then get access to the log object via a factory which would return either the dbbar instance or openlogger depending on whether or not a faces context exists.  Or do people throw errors in lower level methods and just let the higher level calling functions handle and log them?

Thanks!

**Solution**
Using the steer towards dependency injection I've ended up hacking the dBar a bit to make it work both ways.
My business beans all still contain this at the top for easy logging

```
private final static DebugToolbar log = DebugToolbar.get();
```

but have hacked it a bit to make the dBar also act as a Singleton...

```
private static DebugToolbar instance;

// retrieve an instance of this toolbar class
public static DebugToolbar get() {
    if (null == instance) {
        return (DebugToolbar) resolveVariable(BEAN_NAME);
    } else {
        return instance;
    }
}

public static void setInstance(Session session, Database database) {
    instance = new DebugToolbar(session, database);
}
public static void clearInstance() {
    instance = null;
}
```

Then I can continue to use it as before form an Xpage, but when running an XPagesAgent I can call this at the start to pass the required references, allowing the business beans to still 'work' as before with the same logging.

`DebugToolbar.setInstance(session, database);`

and this at the end of the XPagesAgent

`DebugToolbar.clearInstance();`

which I don't know if it's necessary or not but am presuming they'd be errors if the singleton lasts longer than the agent, which i understand it would do

plus obviously some tweaks to the dBar code itself to skip anything associated with the FacesContext if it's not available.

This may well be a horrendous anti-pattern but it appears to work.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: declutter and dependency inject.

Long answer:
Try to look at the MVC pattern. Limit the beans that interact directly with the XPage through EL to a facade pattern. Call your business beans from there and hand over either Java objects or Notes objects like views, documents or sessions etc.

This is absolutely necessary when you want to pack your business beans into a (junit) test harness. So instead of:

```
 BusinessBean.makeInvoices();
```

you would have:

```
 BusinessBean.makeInvoices(session, NotesView, OutputStream);
```

The later function can be called from an XPage, an agent or a standalone Java program ( think JUnit, Jenkins). So instead of figuring out the dependencies inside your bean, you provide them in the call.

This is also called separation of concerns. Your bean does its thing without bothering about the surrounding.

Hope that helps

Comment: cheers. have kind of come up with a compromise which uses dependancy injection with the dBar rather than the business beans themselves to overcome the logging (2) part. for the first one though I see I'll need to pass a reference to my settings object to the business bean too

Answer (score 1):

As mr stwissel said dependency injection is the way to go here.

But with logging I prefer to go Log4j way and avoid passing logger through params.

By Log4j way I mean getting refrence to logger object through static factory method (like Logger.getLogger('some.class')) and leave the configuration loading to log4j framework.

Unfortunatelly I don't know if OpenLog logger can be configured in such a way, that it will automatically read settings from given configuration file (faces-config or other).

You can always write custom appender for log4j that will route logs to OpenLogger (this should be quite easy)

Comment: thanks for the reply. A proper Logging framework sounds like the ideal way to go but I don't think I'm ready to move away from dBar yet. Have come up with a compromise

Answer (score 0):

From experience of developing the logging for OpenNTF Domino API, the biggest issue is Java security exceptions. That includes defining different loggers and logging levels, and also loading a different configuration on the fly. You can handle most of that by using a plugin, but I'm not sure if you want to go that far.

Log4J is a standard Java logging mechanism, but that also hits security options. I think the custom appender for log4j would hit the same security exceptions, unless it's in a plugin. Someone suggested an anonymous logger might work, but I haven't tried that.

OpenNTF Domino API has a variety of logging options in the core plugin rather than the Xsp plugin. BaseOpenLogItem is a core implementation of IOpenLogItem, without any dependencies on facesContext. There is also a logger to log to a file in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT. DominoUtils.handleException(Throwable) or (Throwable,String) will do that logging. The challenge is identifying what code is triggering the exception.